# Cross-thread operation not valid, When adding Button to Panel in c#(Use of Deligate is Not Effective)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have problem in adding button in panel,
I already read how to use `delegate` and I write it in my code,
But after that only this exception is suppressed But no Button Added to my Panel.
Here is My Code

```
public delegate void AddControlToPanelDlgt(Panel panel, Control ctrl);  
    private void AddControlToPanel(Panel panel, Control ctrl)
    {
        if (panel.InvokeRequired)
        {
            panel.Invoke(new AddControlToPanelDlgt(AddControlToPanel), panel, ctrl);
            return;
        }
        if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ctrl.Invoke(new AddControlToPanelDlgt(AddControlToPanel), panel, ctrl);
            return;
        }
        panel.Controls.Add(ctrl); //<-- here is where the exception is raised
    }
```

Comment: You forget `c#-5.0` tag.

Comment: Of course it was effective, you no longer get the exception.  Not seeing the control is a *different* problem.  It could be hidden underneath another control or have the wrong Location so it is off the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)` it is not needed,

```
private void AddControlToPanel(Panel panel, Control ctrl)
{
    if (panel.InvokeRequired)
    {
       panel.Invoke(new AddControlToPanelDlgt(AddControlToPanel), new object[] { panel, ctrl });          
    }
    else
        panel.Controls.Add(ctrl); //<-- here is where the exception is raised
}
```

As per the comments by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813420/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-when-adding-button-to-panel-in-cuse-of-delig#comment31208365_20813420) it is absolutely right that you have added the `Control` successfully but it could be hidden underneath another control or have the wrong Location that's why it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure panel and ctrl is not null first

```
private void AddControlToPanel(Panel panel, Control ctrl)
    {
        if (panel.InvokeRequired)
        {
            panel.Invoke(new Action<Panel, Control>(AddControlToPanel), panel, ctrl);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            panel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
    }
```